# Nested function defenitions

Tags: elixir

i'm just working through Programming Elixir and imlpementing Split.

My code as is follows -

```
defmodule MyEnum do
    def split(l, n) do
        def split_helper([], pre, _n), do: {pre, []}
        def split_helper(l, pre, 0), do: {pre, l}
        def split_helper([h|t], pre, n), do: split_helper(t, [h|pre], n-1)
        split_helper(l, [], n)
    end
end
```

and I am getting the error -
cannot invoke def/2 inside function/macro

Which i take to mean I can't nest named functions. As you can't write recursive anonymous functions and there is no letrec, I am wondering how to nest functions where the nested function is recursive. This is the way I would structure my code in racket as I would never need to use split_helper anywhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions in *Elixir* cannot be nested. Period.

The idiomatic way to implement this would be to have a private function called `do_split/3`.

```rb
defmodule MyEnum do
  def split(l, n), do: do_split(l, [], n)

  defp do_split([], pre, _n), do: {pre, []}
  defp do_split(l, pre, 0), do: {pre, l}
  defp do_split([h|t], pre, n), do: do_split(t, [h|pre], n-1)
end
```

---

Another way to approach the problem would be to simply have several clauses of `split/3` itself.

```rb
defmodule MyEnum do
  def split(l, acc \\ [], n) # default values

  def split([], pre, _n), do: {pre, []}
  def split(l, pre, 0), do: {pre, l}
  def split([h|t], pre, n), do: split(t, [h|pre], n-1)
end
```

---

The least elegant, but still working approach would be to create anonymous function *and pass it through*.

```rb
defmodule MyEnum do
  def split(l, n) do
    split_helper = fn
      [], pre, _, _ -> {pre, []}
      l, pre, 0, _ ->  {pre, l}
      [h|t], pre, n, split_helper ->
        split_helper.(t, [h|pre], n-1, split_helper)
    end
    split_helper.(l, [], n, split_helper)
  end
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! thanks! Your second option was a lightbulb moment for me.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be worth studying the [implementation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/bffb79e553bb541b749db910303da56f0bbe7d66/lib/elixir/unicode/unicode.ex#L276) of [`String.split_at/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split_at/2).

> ```elixir
> def split_at(string, pos) do
>   do_split_at(string, 0, pos, 0)
> end
>
> defp do_split_at(string, acc, desired_pos, current_pos) when desired_pos > current_pos do
>   case next_grapheme_size(string) do
>     {count, rest} -> do_split_at(rest, acc + count, desired_pos, current_pos + 1)
>     nil -> {acc, nil}
>   end
> end
>
> defp do_split_at(string, acc, desired_pos, desired_pos) do
>   {acc, string}
> end
> ```